# MSDeploy RunCommand Priviliges

Tags: msdeploy

I am trying to use the -presync:runCommand option in MSDeploy and no matter what I try to run, I get the same error back:

> Error: A required privilege is not held by the client.

I've tried a handful of items to execute, and none of them work.  Ideally I want to execute an exe on the server as such:

```
-presync:runCommand=C:\MyExecutable.exe,dontUseCommandExe=true
```

I've also tried

```
-presync:runCommand=C:\TestScript.bat
```

And the sample from their [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28WS.10%29.aspx)

```
-presync:runCommand="net stop w3svc"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58):

I found the answer, and it turns out I had already halfway completed it.  In the link I provided in my question, they mention how to add privileges to the WMSvc account, like so:

```
sc privs wmsvc SeChangeNotifyPrivilege/SeImpersonatePrivilege/SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege/SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
```

What it failed to mention is that you must restart WMSvc for this to take affect.

Comment: I've updated the runCommand provider doc to reflect the need to restart WMSvc after running sc privs - thanks for the catch.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, and +1 for someone from Microsoft keeping an eye on Stack Overflow and updating MS documentation. That's great!

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your rules in Microsoft Service Delegation for any operations that are performed out of WWWROOT such as custom folders
   e.g.
   Provider = "runCommand"

State = Enabled

Path =

Path Type = PathPrefix

Actions = *

Identity Type = SpecificUser

UserName = WDeployAdmin

(you'll need to know the password for this, I didn't so I changed the P/W)

Then "Add User To Rule" as "*" and IsRole checked

2. Do the same for provider = "contentPath"
3. Elevate the 'WMSvc' privilages as follows...

sc privs wmsvc SeChangeNotifyPrivilege/SeImpersonatePrivilege/SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege/SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege

4. Restart 'WMSvc'