# Undoing RunCommand Privilege changes for WMSvc

Tags: msdeploy, privileges

I changed the privileges for the WMSvc account by following the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380819/msdeploy-runcommand-priviliges) but after reading the documentation at [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28WS.10%29.aspx) it seems like this is not a recommended practice and it's better to add the "Replace a process level token" privilege for my account, which I've done and it's working.

What do I need to do to revert the privilege changes to WMSvc back to the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has no extra privileges by default so you could try this command:

```
sc privs wmsvc /
```

You want to run "sc qprivs wmsvc" to list what it has on it before you remove them.